# Run php function on selected time

Tags: php

I want to run a php function on my server in a certain time without make the script sleep.

I need this in order to update my database in specific time.

For example a chat room that lasts for 5 minutes.
The chat room have a flag in the database for open status.
I want to change the flag in the database to close after 5 minutes.

```
public function callOnDelay($time, $data)
    {
        //SOME CODE EXECUTED AFTER SOME TIME IS OVER//
    }
```

Comment: Make `cron` do the job?

Comment: Ok thanks for sharing. While we are listing things we want: I could use a new car.

Comment: @PeeHaa Well in java this function is very easy

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways of doing this depending on your OS.

On Linux you can look for **Cron Jobs** (http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml).

On Windows you can look for **Task Scheduler** (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766428.aspx).

Also another, not so reliable, method of doing this is adding a conditional/if in your main script (index.php ?) or a "before function" in your controller (if you are using some kind of framework that supports it) and checking for the last status and doing something with it.